# Angular dropdown value changing All dropdowns value

Tags: angular, select, angular5

I am working on angular 5 and facing issue with dropdown where user can add multiple data.
I have a form where I've added few text boxes and a dropdown, Then i have a add more button which duplicate the row, now each row have dropdown with same ng-model, so changing in one dropdown will reflect changes in all other,
my select code is below

```
  <select [(ngModel)]="subSearch.salesPerson" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">Please select</option>
    <option *ngFor="let option of salesPersonList" [value]="option.UserId">{{option.FullName}}</option>
  </select>
```

How can I manage that I can change only one dropdown at a time and rest don't get effected, Rest all are input box and they are working as accepted

Comment: Can you add some more details like how It is right now? And what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: I have a form where i've added few textboxs and a dropdown, Then i have a add more button which duplicate the row, now each row have dropdown with same ng-model, so changing in one dropdown will refelect changes in all other,

Comment: Can you add the full HTML here and your component code? Also, You want same data data for every dropdown?

Comment: nope, i want different data for every dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing, Don't include ngmodel for every dropdown and change this:

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="passFormControlNameHere" >
    <option value="0">Please select</option>
    <option *ngFor="let option of salesPersonList" [value]="option.UserId">{{option.FullName}}</option>
  </select>
```

The reason it changes for every drop, it uses NgModel which is used for two-way data binding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `ngModel` binding source to an array (instead of `subSearch.salesPerson`). Try something like below.

In your `.ts` file declare an array to hold the selected items.

```
salesPeople = new Array<string>(4); // You will need to change this hard coded value.
```

and in `ngModel`, bind it to each element (instead of one single property)

```
<select [(ngModel)]="salesPeople[i]" class="form-control">
```

This way each `select` will be bound to separate array elements. In the end, you can get the selected sales people list from `salesPeople` array. Checkout the StackBlitz sample I made for demonstration purpose below.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ywzcxc?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

For dynamically managing the array index, you could create a new array every time you add a row (and copy the previous one into that). Add a variable to track your row count and that should be your array's index - or something similar to that.